# Firestore - "Missing or insufficient permissions", but the user is signed in and the rules are fine

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

I'm getting a really "classic" error with Firebase.
As soon as I'm logging in, I get this message:
"Missing or insufficient permissions."

It was working since a while ago, but I'm not able to reconstruct what kind of edit of the code, broke Firebase Auth. The only debug-idea that was making sense was to activate the logging events on Firebase, and so I did.

Here we can see the 'permissions' error:
[Logging events - Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Ulm.png)

Here we can see that the error was generated by accessing to a particular path: [Logging events - Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQrf0.png)

The path is: `users/ngskrFQaVNMngXM0GO4swjv1lpV2`

Here becomes weird, because I checked my Firestore Rules and they're fine. Here you have:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    // Scoped Functions

    function isAdmin() {
      return isSignedIn() && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles.admin == true;
    }

    // End Scoped Functions

    // Rules

    match /products/{id} {
      allow read: if true;

      match /prices/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
      }

      match /tax_rates/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
      }
    }
    
    match /videos/{id} {
      allow read: if isSignedIn();
      allow write: if isAdmin();
    }
    
    match /workout-weeks/{id} {
      allow read: if isSignedIn();
      allow write: if isAdmin();
    }
    
    match /workout-exercises/{id} {
      allow read: if isSignedIn();
      allow write: if isAdmin();
    }

    match /users/{uid} {
      allow read, write: if
        belongsTo(uid) || isAdmin() //SEEMS TO FAIL HERE IN FE, BUT WORKS IN BE.
      ;
    }
    
    match /announcements/{id} {
      allow read: if isSignedIn();
      allow write: if isAdmin();
    }
    // End Rules
    
  }
}

// Global Functions
function isSignedIn() {
    return request.auth != null;
}
function belongsTo(uid) {
    return isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == uid;
}
//function hasMonthlySub() {
    //return request.auth.token.subType == "monthly";
//}
//function hasYearlySub() {
    //return request.auth.token.subType == "yearly";
//}
//function isSubscribed() {
    //return hasMonthlySub() || hasYearlySub();
//}
//function existingData() {
    // return resource.data;
//}
```

To ensure that the rules was working fine, I put the same path in the playground mode inside Firestore Rules. IT IS WORKING. If the user is signed in and he's accessing his own profile, the request should be fine. In this case, the user accessing the profile is also an Admin, so it should work, no matter what.

The only thing that I suspect is that the user make the request without signing in first. So I tried logging events even from `AngularFireAuth.authState`. No way... the user is signed in:
[USER IS SIGNED IN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvLr9.png)

Do you have any suggestions on how to debug further this code?

Comment: I would try to run the app in icognito mode or other browser just to be sure hat there is not auth `token` used that maybe has some issues. Do you use the Firebase auth `onAuthStateChanged` for auth state handling? Is the auth state managed by the Angular package? Maybe there is a bug that there is state that indicates a logged in user but the user is actually not signed in.

Comment: Hello @TarikHuber I tried in incognito mode but I have the same result: https://prnt.sc/13ve8ww at first I have the signed in user but then I get the Missing or Insufficient permissions. I tried to disabled ALL firestore rules and it works without rules, but it should work with rules too. As it seems from the firebase logging, it's trying to get the user in firestore. It should go fine, but it shouldn't

Comment: @TarikHuber also, you can find a FULL copy of my project on this github repo: https://github.com/plungarini/alpha-project